# Phonegap Project not created through php script

Tags: php, cordova, phonegap-build

I can create phonegap project on terminal when use phonegap create command but when i use php script to create phonegap project it is not creating not even display any error message or warning.

PHP :-

```
<?php
   try {
      $command = 'phonegap create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld';
      exec($command);
   }
   catch(Exception $ex) {
      echo $ex->getMessage();
   }  
?>
```

Note: Above Problem is not about how to print exception or warning it is regarding to create phonegap project through php script

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Its misleading that you want a solution to your error messages in php.  We are 2 ppl that though that.  However i provided a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your code:

```
<?php
   try {
      $command = 'phonegap create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld';
      exec($command);
   }
   catch(Exception $ex) {
      echo $ex->getMessage();
   }  
?>
```

Here is what i did.

**1) I installed Phonegap CLI**

**2) I created the environment varible for the php.exe path**

**3) i create a folder c:\php\test.php  with your code in that php file.**

It worked.

I got a folder called "hello" with the respectable files in it.

:)

Comment: Above Problem is not about how to print exception or warning it is mainly regarding to create phonegap project through php script

Comment: Ok let me refrase my answer.

Comment: Thanks it is now working actually i m missing to set the environment variable for node.js through php `$new = '/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin';
       putenv("PATH=$new");`

Comment: Nice, happy i could help :)

Answer (score -1):

As Exception is an object try print_r() function instead of echo.